# Is it possible to metaprogram named queries onto a grails domain class?

Tags: grails, metaprogramming, named-query

Is it possible to metaprogram named queries onto a grails domain class?  If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you mean?  If you have a domain class with 'first' and 'last' fields, grails automagically adds a findByFirst, findByLast, findByFirstAndLast for you, via metaprogramming....

Comment: [named queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html)

Comment: Specifically I want use a plugin to 'add' a `status` field on domain classes.  However, `status` is a separate domain linked to the domain classes with a soft key (see audit-logging).  I want to add some named queries and allow things like findAllByStatus(fooStatus).otherNamedQuery().list()

Answer (score 2):

Domain classes have a [namedQueries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) property that you can use to add your own named queries. If you want to do this using metaprogramming from within a plugin (rather than by editing the domain class directly), you should do it in the [doWithDynamicMethods](http://www.grails.org/Plugin+Dynamic+Methods) closure of the plugin's descriptor file.

Something like this should work:

```
class MyPlugin {

  def doWithDynamicMethods = { applicationContext ->

    application.domainClasses.each { domainClass -> 

      boolean domainClassFilter = domainClass as Boolean

      if (domainClassFilter) {
        domainClass.metaClass.static.myNamedQuery = {->  

          // implementation of your named query goes here. Here is an example implementation
          // that returns all instances with status == 'ready'
          String simpleClassName = domainClass.simpleName
          domainClass.findAll("from $simpleClassName where status = ?", ['ready'])
        } 
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

This will add `myNamedQuery` to every domain class in the application that the plugin is installed in. If you only want to add it to some domain classes, then replace the value of `domainClassFilter` with a more appropriate test.

Comment: That adds a dynamic method to a domain class, not a named query.