# Grails - Adding a where clause to all domain objects

Tags: grails, grails-orm, where-clause

We have a Grails application that connects to a legacy database in which every table has a column called `deleted` which indicates if an entity has been deleted or not (this means data never actually gets deleted from the table, it gets archived after a certain amount of time). For each of our domain objects we would like to add an automatic `where` clause that looks like:

```
where deleted = false
```

so that we do not have to add this explicitly to every query within the application. Is there a way to achieve this in grails?

Comment: Hi, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082524/is-it-possible-to-metaprogram-named-queries-onto-a-grails-domain-class) maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

I use the [Hibernate Filter plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) for these kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that GORM supports this directly.  However, you can take advantage of the hibernate interceptor and add it yourself.  In particular, you can use the [`onPrepareStatement`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onPrepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29) hook to add the where clause to each query that hibernate generates.  For example:

```
// src/groovy/mypackage/MyEntityInterceptor.groovy
package mypackage
class MyEntityInterceptor extends org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor {
    String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        return addNotDeletedClause(sql)
    }
}
// grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
beans = {
    entityInterceptor(MyEntityInterceptor)
}
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to parse the incoming SQL statement to figure out where to insert the `where` clause.